# What's the best choice for streaming audio only to iPhone iOS 3.1.3 using Apple's Http Live Streaming Protocol?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, audio-streaming, ios3.0, http-live-streaming

I'm building an app that deals with streaming music from a server that's using Http Live Streaming Protocol to send the information. 
I'm using AVPlayer (with AVPlayerItem) to decode the m3u8 files that the server is sending but this class is only referenced in iOS 4. 
There's the option of using MPMoviePlayerController's initWithContentUrl: method but prior to 3.2 there's no way to resize the frame, it only plays in fullscreen. Also I want to create a custom player and this class is not suited to this purpose. 
I know about Matt Gallagher's  [AudioStreamer](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer)  class, but this only seems to work with mp3. Is there a way to make this class work with Http Live Streaming?
Is there any way to stream audio only using Http Live Streaming in iOS 3.1.3? 
Thanks